# Scala: ordering in dataframes when using monotonically_increasing_id()

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

Suppose I have a really simple dataframe `df` with one integer column; it looks like this

```
measured_value
--------------
1828
948
2912
2100
[etc.]
```

Using the following I want to add a monotonically increasing id and use this:

```scala
df.createorReplaceView("tmp")
var sql_cmd = "select monotonically_increasing_id() as counter, * from tmp";
var new_df = spark.sql(sql_command);
```

So `new_df` would ideally look like this:

```
counter | measured_value
------------------------
0       | 1828
1       | 948
2       | 2912
3       | 2100
[etc.]
```

However, I don't know whether the original order of the single column `measured_value` from the original dataframe `df` when using an SQL command on it. Can I be sure that Spark SQL does not do that? Or if it does do this, how do I make sure I can add a `counter` such that the order of the original data is intact?

Comment: In general, in SQL, tables represent *unordered* sets, so there is no "order of the original data".  You can sort by a column that represents that ordering.  I don't know if SparkSQL extends SQL to define an ordering on a table, but given that it is sometimes dealing with distributed tables, I would be surprised if it does no.