# Scala: monotonically_increasing_id() in data frames ordered by timestamp

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

This is similar to the setting of an [older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57593364/scala-ordering-in-dataframes-when-using-monotonically-increasing-id) except this time I have a time series with a timestamp such that no timestamp appears in more than 1 record. So suppose I have a really simple dataframe `time_series` with one timestamp and one integer column; it looks like this:

```
timestamp  | measured_value
--------------------------
2019-06-30 | 1828
2019-07-01 | 948
2019-07-02 | 2912
2019-07-03 | 2100
[etc.]
```

Using the following I want to add a monotonically increasing id and use this:

```scala
time_series.createorReplaceView("tmp")
var sql_cmd = """select 
                    monotonically_increasing_id() as counter
                    , * 
                 from 
                    tmp
                 order by
                    timestamp asc""";
var new_time_series = spark.sql(sql_command);
```

So `new_time_series` has the same number of records as `times_series`, and it would ideally look like this:

```
counter | timestamp  | measured_value
-------------------------------------
0       | 2019-06-30 | 1828
1       | 2019-07-01 | 948
2       | 2019-07-02 | 2912
3       | 2019-07-03 | 2100
[etc.]
```

**Question.** Does `counter` preserve the order given by `timestamp`, or more mathematically, is it true that given two elements in `counter`, n_1 and n_2, then n_1 < n_2 if and only if the timestamp next to n_1 is smaller than the 
timestamp next to n_2?